# Are there any benefits to using a specific method to get value from IDataReader?

Tags: c#, database

There are multiple ways to get a value from IDataReader.

```
reader["FirstName"]; // by column name array style.
reader[0];           // by index array style.
reader.GetValue(0);  // by index method style.
reader.GetString(0); // by index using specific method.
```

Is one of those better than the other?  Do any of them have performance drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few circumstances when you should not use the column name. Technically, the column name is converted to an index, so using the index directly will be marginally faster. However, that margin will be dwarfed by the database call itself, so it is really of no consequence. And - assuming you have ascribed semantic meaning to the columns being returned, and are not implementing some kind of generic data processor - using the index makes it much more likely that you will accidentally introduce a bug in the future as the data in the query changes.

Answer (score 2):

`reader.GetValue(0)` is the fastest method.

Using `reader["FirstName"]` calls `reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName")` and then calls `reader.GetValue(0)`. `reader[0]` just calls `reader.GetValue(0)` in it's getter.

Comment: From a readability perspective I'd use the column name variant, though.

Comment: Technically it really depends on the implementation of IDataReader used.  As IDataReader is just an interface there isn't any specific performance associated with it.  Given using SqlDataReader though I would agree that the above is true.

Comment: @AdamGritt, true, but this is from the `OleDbDataReader` implementation.

Comment: You also have to figure the casting/type checking involved in calling GetString vs GetValue. I'd also wonder about caching the name/index pairs ahead of time and then calling GetValue(int) for each record. That would also depend on implementation of GetOrdinal.